# How do I pass information to a new view controller using a segue in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm running into a problem while working on a simple project. This app essentially just displays a collection of images and when I tap one of the images, it is suppose to transition into a new view controller and display the name of the image on a label.

I am new at Swift. Is it something to do with the indexPath that I used in the function to fill the collection view? I tried to see if I could get the indexPath and then pass that into the images array to get the name and send the name in the second view controller but it comes up nil. Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is my CollectionViewController

```
    class ImagePickerViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var images = Data()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
            cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(images.images[indexPath.item])")
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let dest = segue.destination as? FeedPickerViewController{
            if segue.identifier == "detailViewController_segue"{
                let cell = sender as! CollectionViewCell
                let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
                let imgName = images.images[indexPath!.item]
                dest.imgName = imgName
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

This is theViewController that I am segueing to

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var imgName: String!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.text = "Posting Image: \(imgName)"
    }
}
```

and this is the data class

```
class Data {

    let images = ["bear", "bird", "bridge", 
                  "cabin"]
}
```

Comment: First thing you've to change Class Data name to another one because Data is the reserved keyword for Data object!.

Comment: Your code implies that the segue is connected from the collection view cell rather than from the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remember indexPath which is selected cell's

You can use `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` to retrieve selected cell's indexPath

`selectedIndexPath = indexPath`

then pass the data of the selected using selected IndexPath to destination view controller

`dest.imageName = images.images[selectedIndexPath!.item]`

Comment: I implemented the `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` as you suggested but when I run the debugger, I noticed that the function is not being called at all and my selected path variable is nil heading into segue function and coming out in new view controller. Is it because of the `imageView` in the cell? The app is registering a tap on the image rather than cell?

Comment: Make sure the segue(`prepare`) should called after `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` called

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
class ImagePickerViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return DataImage.images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
            cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: DataImage.images[indexPath.item])
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let dest = segue.destination as? FeedPickerViewController{
            if segue.identifier == "detailViewController_segue"{
                let cell = sender as! CollectionViewCell
                let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
                let imgName = DataImage.images[indexPath!.item]
                dest.imgName = imgName
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var imgName: String!

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.text = "Posting Image: " + imgName
    }
}
```

- Use **struct** instead of **Class**

```
struct DataImage {

    static var images = ["bear", "bird", "bridge", "cabin"]
}
```